# Finding convergence center, radius, and interval of power series

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, power-series

I'm working on a problem that asks me to determine the convergence center, radius, and interval of the following power series:

$$\sum^{\infty }_{k=2} \left( k+3\right)^{2}  \left( 2x-3\right)^{k}$$

Here's what I've attempted so far:

To find the convergence center, I set $$(2x-3)^k = 0$$ and solved for x. This gives me x = 3/2, which is the convergence center.

To find the convergence radius, I used the formula $$R = \lim_{k\to\infty}|\frac{a_{k}}{a_{k+1}}|$$, where $$a_k$$ is the coefficient of the $k$th term. So I calculated:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{k\to\infty}|\frac{(k+3)^2}{(k+4)^2}| &= \lim_{k\to\infty}|\frac{k^2+6k+9}{k^2+8k+16}|\\
&= \lim_{k\to\infty}|\frac{1+6/k+9/k^2}{1+8/k+16/k^2}|\\
&= \frac{1}{1}\\
&= 1
\end{align*}

Therefore, the convergence radius is 1.

Now, to find the convergence interval, I know that the series converges for $$|x - 3/2| < R$$, and diverges for $$|x - 3/2| > R$$. So, plugging in the values I found, I get that the series converges for $$|x - 3/2| < 1$$

However, I'm not quite sure if my approach is correct, and I'd appreciate any feedback or guidance on how to correctly find the convergence center, radius, and interval.

Comment: Would the answer change if the series were $\sum_{k = 2}^\infty (k + 3)^2 (4x - 6)^k$?

Comment: $a_k$ is not $(k+3)^2.$

Answer (score 1):

You can as well treat the series as numerical one and apply the d'Alembert ratio test to get
$${(k+4)^2|2x-3|^{k+1}\over (k+3)^2|2x-3|^{k}} \to  |2x-3|$$
Therefore the interior of the interval of convergence coincides with $|2x-3|<1.$ This way of solution is convenient when studying the power series, where some of the exponents are missing: for example
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty  (2k+3)^2(2x-3)^{2k}$$

Answer (score -1):

$$
\sum_{k=2}^\infty(k+3)^2(2x-3)^k=\sum_{k=2}^\infty2^k(k+3)^2\left(x-\frac32\right)^k
$$
So, as Anne Bauval commented, $a_k=2^k(k+3)^2$. Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{a_k}{a_{k+1}}
&=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac12\left(\frac{k+3}{k+4}\right)^2\\
&=\frac12
\end{align}
$$
You have the center of convergence correct, and using the proper radius, we get
$$
\left|x-\frac32\right|\lt\frac12
$$

Comment: I'll leave the endpoints for you.